# Calculate difference and percent difference between rows within a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
Supplier    SKU    PartFull    2022-03-12    2022-03-05    2022-02-26 
A           123A   565         0.0564        0.0543        0.0554
B           123A   565         0.0392        0.0407        0.0432
A           424S   773         0.0121        0.0118        0.0145
A           889L   319         0.1877        0.1900        0.2035
B           889L   319         0.2765        0.2834        0.2299
B           455B   111         0.1233        0.1321        0.1438
```

What I would like to do is take the difference and the percent difference between rows for `SKU`/`PartFull` pairs where both Supplier A and B have data. The result would be as follows:

```
Supplier    SKU    PartFull    2022-03-12    2022-03-05    2022-02-26 
A           123A   565         0.0564        0.0543        0.0554
B           123A   565         0.0392        0.0407        0.0432
DIFF        123A   565         0.0172        0.0136        0.0122
PCT_DIFF    123A   565         0.3096        0.2505        0.0432
A           424S   773         0.0121        0.0118        0.0145
A           889L   319         0.1877        0.1900        0.2035
B           889L   319         0.2765        0.2834        0.2299
DIFF        889L   319         -0.0888       -0.0934       -0.0264
PCT_DIFF    889L   319         -0.4731       -0.4916       -0.1297
B           455B   111         0.1233        0.1321        0.1438
```

For the rows where there is only one supplier for a `SKU`/`PartFull`, we do not calculate a DIFF or a PCT_DIFF row. The `SKU`/`PartFull` pairing will always be consistent.

Comment: Is it necessary to insert those rows or we can have the result separately, because inserting those rows will be very inefficient for very large data

Comment: @Epsi95 I suppose we could filter them out, perform difference calculations, append them back into the dataframe and then sort the results. But I still can't come up with a way to get the missing rows even in those circumstances.

Comment: @ahh_real_numbers did the solution proposed work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by setting `["Supplier", "SKU", "PartFull"]`  as index (so they will not be removed when grouping) and then grouping by `["Supplier", "SKU"]` to perform `diff` and `pct_change`

```
grouped = df.set_index(["Supplier", "SKU", "PartFull"]).groupby(level=[1,2])

diff = (-grouped.diff().dropna()).reset_index().assign(Supplier="DIFF")
pct_change = (-grouped.pct_change().dropna()).reset_index().assign(Supplier="PCT_CHANGE")


pd.concat([df, diff, pct_change], axis=0).sort_values(["SKU", "PartFull"])



     Supplier   SKU  PartFull  2022-03-12  2022-03-05  2022-02-26
0           A  123A       565    0.056400    0.054300    0.055400
1           B  123A       565    0.039200    0.040700    0.043200
0        DIFF  123A       565    0.017200    0.013600    0.012200
0  PCT_CHANGE  123A       565    0.304965    0.250460    0.220217
2           A  424S       773    0.012100    0.011800    0.014500
5           B  455B       111    0.123300    0.132100    0.143800
3           A  889L       319    0.187700    0.190000    0.203500
4           B  889L       319    0.276500    0.283400    0.229900
1        DIFF  889L       319   -0.088800   -0.093400   -0.026400
1  PCT_CHANGE  889L       319   -0.473095   -0.491579   -0.129730
```